# How to check special characters in a string using Yup?

Tags: javascript, yup

For Example, Bank account number cannot have special characters and I would like to validate the user input using `Yup` and show error in case of special characters like @,#,$ etc and emoji's.

Main intention here is to know the use of `regex` with `Yup`.

Note: I can use `Yup.oneOf` and restrict the user just to enter the integers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Yup.matches(/* regex here */, /* error message */)`